# delete rest call from chrome to couchDB

Tags: rest, google-chrome, http, couchdb

I am able to do a GET and POST request from chrome to couchDB.
The delete request fails for options preflight error.

Q - how to make couchDB answer the options preflight ?

- chrome version 53.
- couchdb version 1.6
- cors is enabled  with this config

  cors: {
  credentials: "true",

headers: "accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer, x-csrf-token",

methods: "GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE",

origins: "*"
},

error on google-chrome console :

```
 OPTIONS http://<IP>/association/soc105380149348193148074 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://<IP>/association/soc105380149348193148074. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

IP is of course replaced by the real one. ;)

Answer (score 0):

With CORS enabled, the default methods allowed are `GET` and `POST`. Thus, to support `DELETE` (and any others) you'll need to modify your server's configuration.

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/http.html#cors/methods), the relavent config is `cors/methods`.

Comment: I have updated the question. other browsers are behaving correctly, only the new version of chrome is behaving this way.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this same issue in Chrome 54, however it looks like a fix has been merged on the [CouchDB GitHub](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-chttpd/pull/135), presumably we will see it in the next release.